# Cannot edit UITableViewCell y-offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, offset

I have a `UIViewController` that needs two separate table views.

I'm using `storyboard` to drag the two table views onto my controller, but once I drag a table view cell onto each of them, the prototype cell within one of the table views all of a sudden has a larger `y-offset` from the top of the `tableView`.

When I go to the Size Inspector for that cell, then to the View section, all of the X, Y, Width, and Height values are greyed out so I can't edit the position of the cell.

This is only an issue when the view controller is embedded in a navigation controller.

Any ideas for a fix to this offset so my tables don't look silly next to each other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uncheck your view controller's "Adjust Scroll View Insets" option on attribute inspector in IB. When displayed in the context of a navigation controller, only one scroll view (table view) will have its insets adjusted. This is why you see a difference between table views.

If you need the insets adjusted, just set them manually in code.

Answer (score 0):

These two tutorials will help you learning, how to adjust the `prototype cell`:

**1)**  [Tutorial 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)

**2)**      [Tutorial 2](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells)